# Swift: Recently clicked view?

Tags: swift

Is there a property of UIView that returns the most recently clicked (or possibly otherwise "gestured") subview?

I want to have a computed property `currentPosition` that simply gets a the `position` property (a property I've defined for my subclass of UIView) from the last-clicked view.

Right now I have an optional instance property `let clickedView = UIView?`, and inside my gesture handlers I say 
`clickedView = gestureRecognizer.view` 

and then I have the computed instance property declared as:

`currentPosition: Position? { return clickedView?.position }` but it would be great to have this be simpler, and especially not have to assign `clickedView = gestureRecognizer.view` every time.

Comment: "Right now I have an optional instance property" Well, that's the way I would have done it.

Comment: that also would be my first idea. maybe somehow with protocol, delegates or a default closure you can put it in your own tailored gesture recogniser ho assign this to your instance property

Answer (score 0):

Possible you can play with **tag** value. Whenever the touch event is happened loop all the subview and set the tag to zero and set the new touched view tag to some value like 100.

touch event

->set all view tag's to zero

->set the latest view tag's to 100

Loop all the subview

->if tag value is 100 that's the latest view

Comment: and then hope that you don't have any other processes which depend on the tag value!  Why not do the thing you say you don't want to, and just update the clickedView property?